# 12.04 is not detecting onboard Intel GMA 950! Need to install driver Manually!

Tags: intel-graphics, resolution

My motherboard model is ASUS P5GC-MX/1333 and built in graphics card is Intel GMA950. Unfortunately, Ubuntu 12.04 is not detecting on board graphics card. Display option under settings menu is showing unknown hardware, therefore, default resolution is always 1024*768 and fonts are not clear and sometimes fuzzy. My question is, how can I install driver for Intel GMA 950 manually? So, that I can fix screen resolution. Thank you in anticipation.

Answer (score 3):

Recently I had the same issue with a HP Pavilion dv6426us with the same Intel on-board graphics.

Please, note that following steps are at your own risk!

Add this [ppa](https://launchpad.net/~xorg-edgers/+archive/ppa) to your repos list:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
```

Then run update:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Thereafter the system should determine the Intel graphics properly.

**Read carefully the information on this [page](https://launchpad.net/~xorg-edgers/+archive/ppa) before taking these actions!**